# Returning as many complete concatenated rows as possible up to a length limit

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe with a single column (elements as strings) and a certain number of rows. The length of the string of each row can be variable.

I want to concatenate the rows into a single string. Currently, I can do something like this (where `output` is the column with the strings I want to concatenate):

```py
toprint = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['\n|-\n'.join(df['output'].str.strip('"').tolist())]})['text'].item()
```

The problem is that `toprint` cannot have more than a certain size, and I want the first k bytes of `toprint` as a result. So one way I can work around this is to do this:

```py
toprint = toprint[:2096900]
```

The issue is that the result would often be that I get part of a row (as it gets cut off when the length limit is reached). I want to return as many **complete** rows as possible in the string, up to the length limit. How can I do that as efficiently as possible, without iterating through each row of the dataframe (i.e, without using something like `df.iterrows`)?

Rough example: the dataframe contains five rows of length 25. The maximum length of the concatenated string is 80. Currently, the concatenated string would contain the first three rows and part of the fourth row. I want the string to contain only the first three rows.

Comment: Do you just want to do this once? For instance if you have 10 rows of 10 characters and the limit is 30, would you want one string of 30 or 4 strings of [30, 30, 30, 10]?

Comment: @mozway, one string of 30. That string contains the first three strings, concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

```
df['str_length'] = df['col1'].str.len() # create column with length of strings
df['str_length_cum'] = df['str_length'].cumsum() # create column with cumulative length of strings
df = df[df['str_length_cum'] < 2096900] # filter with threshold
df
```

Then you can do "your thing" on the remaining dataframe.
This will ensure that you do not exceed your limit.

Comment: Or just `df[df['col1'].str.len().cumsum() < 2096900]` to save creating unwanted columns. You probably should also allow for the `'\n|-\n'` string separator as that could get significant e.g. `df[(df['col1'].str.len()+4).cumsum() < 2096900]`

Comment: @Nick - thanks, however prefer to make it more explainable to the user

Comment: Fair enough - but I do think you should take account of the separator that OP wants to add between strings.